# Repository in PRE_WRITE event returns query data, not saved data

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

During a PUT call to an item I need to get the current saved values in order to compare them to request params.

Say the PUT call contains a `name` parameter that is different from the currently saved one.

I thought getting the entity with `$repository->findOneBy` would return the saved value but it's not, I'm getting the PUT param value instead.

The setup is taken from https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events :

```php
    const ALLOWED_METHOD = Request::METHOD_PUT;

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::VIEW => [
                ['preWriteWorkflow', EventPriorities::PRE_WRITE],

            ],
        ];
    }

    public function preWriteWorkflow(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event)
    {

        $entity = $event->getControllerResult();

        if (!($entity instanceof MyEntity)) {
            return;
        }
        
        $route = "/{$entity->getId()}";
        
        $result = $this->checkRequestFromControllerResult($event, $route);
        if (!$result) {
            return;
        }
        
        // Getting entity from repository in order to get the currently saved value
        $savedEntity = $this->MyEntityRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $entity->getId()]);
       
        // Both will return the Name value of the PUT call
        // Shouldn't $savedEntity return the currently saved name ?  
        $entity->getName();
        $savedEntity->getName();
    }
```

What is the reason behind this behavior? Is there a way to get `eventArgs` injected in this method so that I can use `getEntityChangeSet` or `hasChangedField`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the reason behind this behavior?

This is doctrine behaviour. Once you've fetched an entity, the instance is stored and always returned. Given that, you have one and only one instance of your entity during request's lifecycle.

```
$event->getControllerResult() === $repository->findBy($id); //true !
```

Roughly, Api-platform calls Doctrine and fetch your entity while executing the ReadListener. Because this is an object, doctrine's **find***() methods always returns a pointer/reference to the entity, even if it is updated.
Yes, during a PUT request, the updated instance is the fetched one, in order to trigger doctrine update actions at the end of the request.

An easy way to keep an instance of the so called  *previous object* is to **[clone](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/implementing-wakeup-or-clone.html#implementing-wakeup-or-clone)** it before the [Deserialization event](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events/#built-in-event-listeners).

Note that this strategy is used by api-platform with the `security_post_denormalize` and `previous_object` [security attributes](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/security/#executing-access-control-rules-after-denormalization).

**EDIT**

Working on a similar use case, i've found that the `ReadListener` stores the current object within the `Request` under the "data" key, whereas the previous object is stored within the "previous_data" key.

```php
$entity = $request->get('data');
$previousEntity = $request->get('previous_data'); // This is a clone.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is it really the way to go then? My goal is to set a flag in case some specific fields are modified.

Comment: I never try to do it but according to [this doc](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks-event-argument) i guess it is possible by using directly a doctrine event subscriber instead of an api-platform one.

Comment: Ok thanks I was hoping to do so in API Platform context but it doesn't seem possible indeed.